# Slow debug build when using DexGuard in Android Studio with Gradle

Tags: android-studio, dexguard

The debug build is very slow when using DexGuard in Android Studio.

Comment: Which configuration are you using for your debug builds? It is very unusual that debug builds with DexGuard would be slow as obfuscation, shrinking and optimization is disabled (when using 'dexguard-debug.pro' as default configuration).

Comment: Don't remember. Stopped using DexGuard (new pricing).

Comment: Also - I don't think instant run will work with DexGuard enabled on the debug build.

Answer (score 5):

Make DexGuard to work only during "Release" build, change the "build.gradle" file:

1. Move "apply plugin: 'dexguard'" from the global scope to the "Release" build type scope
2. Remove the "getDefaultDexGuardFile" call from the "Debug" build

For example:

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            ...
        }
        release {
            apply plugin: 'dexguard'
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
            proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**#Retrofit**
-keep class retrofit.** { ; }

-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@retrofit2.http. ;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
@retrofit2.http.* ;
}

-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable

-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault

-dontobfuscate - only in debug mode production mode dont use this

-dontoptimize

-dontshrink

Please use in this lines Dexguard-project.txt file. that's all. Enjoy your coding...
```